# Using FFTW with anti-periodic boundary conditions

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I'm coding lattice gauge theory simulation in C++ and to compute observable i need to calculate green's function of 3d laplace operator of the photon field A_mu with anti-periodic boundary conditions. So allowed set of anti-periodic momenta is (pi/L)*(2*k+1), k ∈ (0..L-1). I wrote the parallel code with fourier transform but it's too slow to be practical for calculations. I wonder can one use FFTW (and DFT in general) for this kind of task?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's too vague to be useful.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Anti-periodic means f(x+L) = -f(x), it's changes sign when crosses the boundary

Comment: If your fourier transform is anti periodic, it just means the phases/frequencies contributing to the signal are all anti periodic in period L, and all of the periodic components in period L are provably zero.  Arrange your FFT so the periodic signals are every 2nd entry and skip calculating them?  If I can still grasp fourier transforms in my head (unlikely, it has been decades), that should be the even/odd outputs with suitably aligned input?

Comment: @Yakk All frequencies in the DFT are periodic, none are anti-periodic.

Answer (score 0):

Double the size of your array, from `L` to `2*L`, and fill the second half using the anti-periodic condition `f(x+L) = -f(x)`. In a multi-dimensional setting you can do this for each dimension in turn. You can now compute the FFT, manipulate it as required, and compute the IFFT. The first half of the result is the part that corresponds to your domain, the other half you just ignore.

Depending on the operation you apply in the frequency domain, you might get away with a smaller transform size: If you operation needs, say, `K` samples around each data point to get a reasonable approximation, then you can pad your data with `K` samples on each side (the padding on the left can be put at the end of the array as well, as the FFT assumes periodicity). This leaves an edge effect from the leftmost value in the padded array to the rightmost one, but this edge effect happens `K` samples away from your domain, and so should have little effect on it. If `K` is close to `L/2`, or larger, then doubling the array size is the simpler solution.